# Trailing return type, declval and reference qualifiers: can they work together?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype, ref-qualifier

Consider the following example:

```
#include <utility>

struct A { void f() {} };
struct B { void f() & {} };
struct C { void f() && {} };

template<typename T>
auto f() -> decltype(std::declval<T>().f())
{}

int main() {
    f<A>();
    // f<B>(); // (*)
    f<C>();
}
```

When invoked with `B` (line `(*)`), the code does not compile anymore for `std::declval` converts `T` to an rvalue reference type in the specific case.
If we change it slightly as it follows, we have the opposite problem:

```
// ...

template<typename T>
auto f() -> decltype(std::declval<T&>().f())
{}

// ...

int main() {
    f<A>();
    f<B>();
    // f<C>(); // (*)
}
```

Now line at `(*)` won't work for `std::declval` converts the type to an lvalue reference type in the specific case.

Is there any way to define an expression that accepts the type `T` if it has a member function `f`, no matter what's its reference qualifier?

---

<sub>I don't have any real case in which I would use that and I cannot make any real example of use.

This question is for the sake of curiosity, nothing more.

I understand that there is a reason if the *ref-qualifier* is there and I should not try to break the design of the class.</sub>

Comment: How about `decltype(&T::f)`?

Comment: Won't work for overloaded `f`

Comment: @Brian Well, it would work in this minimal example, but it doesn't work if you have arguments to be used in the _invokation_.

Comment: I don't immediately see any value for `f() &;`, but can't you make use of sfinae and overload the global `f()` ?

Comment: @Arunmu Yes, I can, but I would like to have only one function in the solution. Moreover, as mentioned in the question, this is for curiosity, not because I see any use for `f() &`. ;-)

Comment: The best I came up with was [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/43YuFRNke1wV1voJ). But you can't put lambdas in unevaluated context so it's not really an answer.

Comment: @krzaq It's an answer indeed, I appreciate the effort. I would like to have a solution that doesn't use external libraries (ie hana) anyway, but feel free to post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: [Something like this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7FTRRLksbHcm2KYa), perhaps?

Comment: @bogdan Not a perfect solution, but a working one, of course. It adds two more functions unfortunately, but I guess there is no way with only one function...

Comment: "a member function `f`" - does `int f(int, int);` count?

Comment: @T.C. Yes. Maybe the example should have been made using parameters, but I didn't take into account them while I was writing it. My fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a type trait that returns true if expression `declval<T>().f(declval<Args>()...)` is a valid call. Then pass in `U&` and `U&&` indicating an lvalue or rvalue object of type `T`.

```c++
namespace detail{
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class... Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

  template<template<class...> class, class=void, class...>
  struct can_apply : false_type { };

  template<template<class...> class L, class... Args>
  struct can_apply<L, void_t<L<Args...>>, Args...> : true_type {};

  template<class T>
  using rvalue = decltype(declval<T>().f());
  template<class T>
  using lvalue = decltype(declval<T&>().f());

  template<class T>
  using can_apply_f
    = integral_constant<bool, detail::can_apply<rvalue, void_t<>, T>{} ||
                              detail::can_apply<lvalue, void_t<>, T>{}>;
}

template<class T>
enable_if_t<detail::can_apply_f<T>{}>
f();
```

In C++17 this gets a bit simpler:

```c++
namespace detail{
  auto apply=[](auto&&g,auto&&...xs)->decltype(decltype(g)(g).f(decltype(xs)(xs)...),void()){};

  template<class T>
  using ApplyF = decltype(apply)(T);

  template<class T>
  using can_apply_f = std::disjunction<std::is_callable<ApplyF<T&>>, std::is_callable<ApplyF<T&&>>>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Boost.Hana's [`overload_linearly`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#gaa46de6f618d9f14edb1589b36b6e75ec) to test both variants:

```
template<typename T>
using lval_of = add_lvalue_reference_t<decay_t<T>>;

auto call_f = hana::overload_linearly(
    [](auto&& t) -> decltype(move(t).f()){},
    [](auto&& t) -> decltype(declval<lval_of<decltype(t)>>().f()){}
);

template<typename T>
auto f() -> decltype(call_f(declval<T>()))
{}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/43YuFRNke1wV1voJ)